# 404 error with empty message when posting to /projects/:id/time-records

Tags: activecollab

When posting the following payload to "/projects/1/time-records" I am getting a response with a 404 error code and an empty error message:

`{"task_id":"1","value":"1:00","user_id":"1","job_type_id":1,"record_date":"2018-06-22"}`

Is there anything obvious that I am overlooking?